# SQL Developer 4.0.2 install on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, windows-7-x64

[image][image: SQL Developer error]
[image]
I made a few of them on the computer I got the same error. could not figure out this question. sql developer normally opens but then the image begins to fade. not clicked on anything. system is unwieldy. buttons as the picture opens. 
The two buttons at the same time seems to be open

Comment: I've fixed the picture link, but I don't understand the text that goes with it enough to clean it up. Can you update that and explain the situation a bit more clearly?

Comment: no button does not work when I open sql developer. Sql developer 3 is operating normally. but when I run the sql developer 4.02 I went on button is missing. I want to add new links, but I've been a white page opens. When I arrived on the button with the mouse begins to appear. This problem is probably just my computer I installed the same in his friend's computer. I've tried the following operating systems

Comment: windows server 2008 64bit,windows server 2012 64bit, windows 7 64bit and 32bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
thanks you very much...
SQL Developer 4.0.2 install on Windows 7 64 bit screen solution

Comment: Could you add some text to explain this please? It looks like you're saying that the 'Oracle' look-and-feel is (very) broken in 64-bit mode, so the solution is to use the Windows look-and-feel, is that correct? Or is it a Java version issue?