# Oracle Sql Developer 4.1 menus are not correctly drawn

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have been experiencing GUI drawing problems within Windows 8.1 Pro(x64) with 64Bit JDK 8u45.Adding the JVM property "sun.java2d.noddraw=true" has no effect. The drop down menus are not correctly rendered. In addition some window controls are missing in the dialog boxes. Please see the attached image for details:

[image: Drop Down menu problem]

Is Oracle aware of these problems ? I am asking since I have not found a solution yet. If someone knows anything about this issue, please post in here, I appreciate.

Comment: I would recommend you to use the Oracle bug report, or (and maybe it is more effective) tell about this weird bug to Jeff Smith ( Sql developer product owner ) http://thatjeffsmith.com

Comment: Product manager, sorry for mistype

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SQL Developer 4.0.2 install on Windows 7 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553391/sql-developer-4-0-2-install-on-windows-7-64-bit)

Tools->preferences->Environmental->Look and Feel->window (change oracle to windows)

Comment: efsal harikasın, kafayı yemek üzereydim. u r great !!